# How can I make a scatterplot for this dataset (RStudio)

Tags: r, statistics, scatter-plot

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a scatterplot with the concentration of Enterococci against the Months from this [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frkxU.png).

As of now, I've tried this code:

```
plot(Enterococci..cfu.100ml. ~ Month, data=bacteria_data)
```

but to no success, since it produces a 'need finite xlim values' error. Is there a way around this?

The data:

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c("Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach"), Longitude = c(151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 
151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 
151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 
151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324), Latitude = c(-33.63587, -33.63587, 
-33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, 
-33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, 
-33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587
), Date = c("2018-01-25", "2018-02-07", "2018-02-19", "2018-01-19", 
"2018-02-01", "2018-03-08", "2018-03-14", "2018-10-09", "2018-10-31", 
"2018-11-07", "2018-11-19", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-25", "2018-06-07", 
"2018-06-13", "2018-03-26", "2018-04-10", "2018-05-09", "2018-09-10", 
"2018-09-14"), Enterococci..cfu.100ml = c(6L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 33L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Month = c("January", "February", "February", "January", "February", 
    "March", "March", "October", "October", "November", "November", 
    "May", "May", "June", "June", "March", "April", "May", "September", 
    "September"), Day.of.Week = c("Thursday", "Wednesday", "Monday", 
    "Friday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Monday", "Monday", "Friday", "Thursday", 
    "Wednesday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Monday", 
    "Friday")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 2):

The xlim in your error refers to RHS of the formula `y ~ x` you are using in `Enterococci..cfu.100ml. ~ Month`, `x` should be numeric. We can easily `strftime` the date to get numeric month.

```
plot(Enterococci..cfu.100ml ~ strftime(Date, '%m'), data=df, xlim=c(1, 12))
```

[image]

If you want months as x labels, try

```
plot(Enterococci..cfu.100ml ~ strftime(Date, '%m'), data=df, xlim=c(1, 12), xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=1:12, labels=month.abb[1:12])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somehting like this:

Key feature is to transform the x-axis to date format (here we use `lubridate's` `ymd` function. Then use `geom_point()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date),
         Month = month(Date, abbr = TRUE, label= TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y= Enterococci..cfu.100ml))+
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c("Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", "Avalon Beach", 
"Avalon Beach"), Longitude = c(151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 
151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 
151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324, 
151.3324, 151.3324, 151.3324), Latitude = c(-33.63587, -33.63587, 
-33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, 
-33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, 
-33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587, -33.63587
), Date = c("2018-01-25", "2018-02-07", "2018-02-19", "2018-01-19", 
"2018-02-01", "2018-03-08", "2018-03-14", "2018-10-09", "2018-10-31", 
"2018-11-07", "2018-11-19", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-25", "2018-06-07", 
"2018-06-13", "2018-03-26", "2018-04-10", "2018-05-09", "2018-09-10", 
"2018-09-14"), Enterococci..cfu.100ml = c(6L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 33L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Month = c("January", "February", "February", "January", "February", 
    "March", "March", "October", "October", "November", "November", 
    "May", "May", "June", "June", "March", "April", "May", "September", 
    "September"), Day.of.Week = c("Thursday", "Wednesday", "Monday", 
    "Friday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Monday", "Monday", "Friday", "Thursday", 
    "Wednesday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Monday", 
    "Friday")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```